# Windows 10 v1703 update removed network overview from start menu

Tags: windows-10-v1703

Prior to the v1703 update a right click on the start menu network option produced a view of all networks - including those currently not active.
After the update, the view is a fairly pointless summary of only the current live connection.

How do I get the old full view back again?

Comment: Hi Ian, Are you able to provide an example with a before and after? (the before could be sourced from google, etc)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created a one line batch file containing:

> control netconnections

I then added a shortcut to this file to my start menu.